# How to prevent scrolling of text in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, dosbox

I been trying to create a text editor using the assembly language. I am using al,03h(80x25) graphics mode. After using enter (after the 6th line), the console would automatically scroll up. I save the entered text on the console to a array (string). Then output the string each time, anything new is entered. So, after press enter, it would clear the screen and  output the string again. Is there any way to prevent it from scrolling. 
here is my output of the array code

```
 OUTPUT_BUFFER PROC
     mov di,offset file_size
        mov [di],ax
        mov bx,offset buffer
        mov si,offset file_size
        mov cx,[di]
        mov ah,02h
        mov dl,0
        mov dh,0
        mov bh,0
        int 10h
        wrtittt:
        mov ah,2
        mov dl,[bx]
        int 21h
        inc bx
        dec cx
        jnz wrtittt

    ret
    OUTPUT_BUFFER ENDP
```

Comment: If you draw text on screen "manually", either by writing to VGA memory or using char-at-a-time output functions, you can avoid outputting the CR / LF at all, and just use cursor-movement stuff to put visible text where it belongs.  You haven't commented your code at all, but it looks like you're using a DOS char-at-a-time function already; IDK what that int 10h BIOS call does.  (If you aren't already doing so, you'll want echo disabled, so user input keypresses don't show up on screen themselves, only via your code printing them).

Comment: @peterCordes the int 10h sets the cursor postion at 0,0 before the printing starts. I am printing one character at a time. and I am using int 16h ah,00h for keyboard input

Comment: Ok, so you already know all the functions you might need to handle line-endings manually instead of letting it wrap+scroll.  IDK if that's the only way; perhaps a different text-output function (like BIOS instead of DOS) would handle scrolling differently, but real full-screen text editors do need to keep track of the whole screen.

Comment: @peterCordes if i do the line end manually, lets say without the LF/CR, and save the file, and if I open it up on notepad, the enter wouldn't show up.

Comment: No, I meant to manually move the cursor when you see a CR/LF in your string.  So you still know where the line endings are, and still save the file with them present, but you don't output them with an `int 21h` system call.

Comment: @peterCordes I see what you mean.

Comment: consider the screen content "formatted" view of the data, like when register contains 16 bits (16x 0 or 1), but you output it as decimal or hexadecimal value, or as colour or sound. So the internal text data may contain CR/LF (or LF only), and the output to screen, or save to disk is "interpretation" of them, and can "reformat" them as needed for best fit. For example text editors often store chunks of text with some pointer table into them, to speed up insert/delete operations within large files, but when you save such text into file, all chunks are joined together into it, in one large text.